# Manhwa where the female lead got reincarnated a few times to re-do her life after killing herself. In one of her lives, she ran off with a painter

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

Way back I found a manhwa accidentally and read it just because I was bored but the plot was so good I could not put my phone down after it, but at that point in time only a few chapters were out and now I want to read it again, I cannot remember what it is.

Here are the few details I can remember: the female lead (FL) was a noble, she got betrayed somehow and in the end she killed herself. She got reincarnated to her younger self and vowed to never get herself near the life she had before she got reincarnated. At some point in the story, she got reincarnated a few times and one time was she ran off with a painter. They had a simple life but a happy one. She had a kid with the painter guy but her brother found them and brought her back to her family. Her brother killed the painter and her father wanted to kill her child too and make her the second wife of a noble older guy. At the end, she killed herself and her child, then woke up, seeing she got reincarnated again.

The female protagonist has ebony black hair.
She's from an aristocratic family.
Before she died, I think her husband was royalty and somehow caused her death too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [*The Broken Ring: This Marriage Will Fail Anyway*](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/5o3xoq1/the-broken-ring-this-marriage-will-fail-anyway).

> When six-year-old Inés laid eyes on the handsome heir to House
> Escalante, she promptly made the boy her fiancé. Since noble men are
> all the same, she figured she might as well choose a pretty one. But
> Lord Cárcel isn't ready for this sort of commitment just yet, and he
> spends the next decade and a half avoiding the marriage at all costs!
>
> Luckily, that's no trouble for Inés, as this marriage failing is
> exactly what she wants. In fact, he has her blessing to sow his wild
> oats as long as he stays out of her business. Unfortunately, being a
> playboy isn't as fun when your fiancée gives you permission. And
> doesn't this mean she's cheating on him too? Now, Cárcel is determined
> to change Inés' mind about him and prove he can be the husband she's
> always wanted.

At one point she marries a penniless artist's assistant. You can read the first few chapters for [free on Tappytoon](https://www.tappytoon.com/en/chapters/316334406?).

Comment: thank you so much!❤️

Comment: @newbiekate - [You're very welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)